# Remove Characters in Date/Time document.write script

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, document.write

I have searched for various ways to remove 23:59:59 GMT-0400 (EDT) from a Javascript function I am trying to run. I just want to display Tue Apr 30 2013 (for example). Here is what I have so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var now = new Date();
    document.write(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59));
</script>
```

Which outputs...

**Tue Apr 30 2013 23:59:59 GMT-0400 (EDT)**

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest using moment.js for date parsing, Lots of control for only 5kb. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: `dateString.substring(0,15)`

Comment: @adeneo I wasn't able to get that working properly with my script - could you possibly elaborate at all? Is this just slicing the script?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I'm looking into moment.js now! I was able to write up a script doing what I want (similar to above) but the formatting is still wrong. I'll keep working on it though, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var now = new Date();
    document.write(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59).toDateString());
</script>
```

Comment: That solves the issue of not having 23:59:59 GMT-0400 (EDT) attached - although the original script was written to display the last day of the month. The script you offered shows the current date.